Will Django Transaction Stop Other Connections From Selecting Until Its Completed
In Django I have a table that contains records that need to be processed by celery workers.
The way this works is that the worker will grab the next X number of rows from the table in a batch to process, and then mark them processed. When using one worker this has been fine, but the amount of rows as increased and I would like to add more workers.
My concern is that the other workers will grab the same rows and try to process them.
That being said I have implemented the following logic.
from django.db import models

class Row(models.Model):
    processed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    worker = models.ForeignKey('Worker', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class Worker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

# these functions are all run in their own process from celery
def get_rows_to_process(worker):
   
    batch_size = 10

    with transaction.atomic():
        rows = Row.objects.select_for_update().filter(processed=False, worker__isnull=True)[:batch_size]
        if rows:
            rows.update(worker=worker)
    return rows

def process_rows_for_worker(worker):
    rows = get_rows_to_process(worker)
    for row in rows:
        # Process the row here
        row.processed = True
        row.save()

What I want to know is, will that transaction block prevent the other workers from selecting those rows until the select and subsequent update is finished? Esentially locking those rows so that other workers wont perform the select request until the upodate is finished.
